# How to configure web.config to load resources form external server

Tags: visual-studio, url-rewriting, web-config, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing a web application in Visual Studio 2013 and am getting my data from an external server. For this reason I disable the web securtiy in my browser and define absolute URLs in my application. Now whenever I'm deploying the applicaiton, I have to adopt the URLs (which of course get's forgotten the first time) and also I have to explain the setup to evey person new in the porject.

After getting a bit fimilar with the web.config file, I tried to setup some rules, to rewirte this urls to the data webserver, but failed.

All my relative urls start with the same identifyer, and should be mapped to an external server. This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>


      <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite calls to rest.oms to the actuall webserver">
          <match url="^/IDENTFIER/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://EXTERNAL_SERVER/IDENTFIER/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

However, it is not working so far. Can somebody help me please.

Best Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Have you considered Web.config transforms ? If you create a configuration for each deployement, the URL will be automatically transformed and no additional work will be required.

Comment: The web.config is not deployed to the server, it's a javascript only project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to rewrite from external url, if you have ARR module.

1) You need to install [ARR module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) for your IIS

2) In IIS manager you should enable reverse proxy

2.1) On server node click "Application Request Routing Cache"

2.2) Click "Server proxy settings" and click "Enable proxy", then "Apply"

3) Slightly fix your rewrite rule regexp (remove starting slash):

```
<rule name="Rewrite calls to rest.oms to the actuall webserver">
    <match url="^IDENTFIER/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://EXTERNAL_SERVER/IDENTFIER/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Then your rule should work.

Comment: I just gets this works, the question is 4 years old and I'm not working on this anymore. Thanks for answering it :)